# Attaching local thumbnail to Discord Embed

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've tried everything, and nothing is working. How would I attach a local thumbnail in Discord? The image is inside the images directory

[image]

msg.py:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title="Game Started", description=body)
embed.add_field(name=captain1, value=', '.join(team_one), inline=False)
embed.add_field(name=captain2, value=', '.join(team_two))
embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"attachment://images/elite.png")


await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The thumbnail is not showing

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to send the file as well
2. The url in `set_thumbnail` should just be `attachment://{FILENAME}`, without the actual path since it refers to the attachment of the message

```py
file = discord.File("images/elite.png")

embed = discord.Embed(title="Game Started", description=body)
embed.add_field(name=captain1, value=', '.join(team_one), inline=False)
embed.add_field(name=captain2, value=', '.join(team_two))
embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"attachment://{file.filename}")  # you could just do `attachment://elite.png`, but this is a more "procedural" way

await ctx.send(embed=embed, file=file)
```